# Need to represent what food an animal can eat as an array of strings but have food objects instead

Tags: java, string, object, inheritance

I hope that I explain this clearly. I have an animal (abstract class) that has an eats property, this is meant to be an array of strings representing what each animal can eat. This is how my animal class looks.

```
public abstract class Animal {
    String[] eats;

    public Animal (String[] eats) {
        this.eats = eats;
    }
}
```

I also have a lion class which extends my animal class. The spec tells me that my lion will eat celery and steak. The constructor in my lion class is as follows (it has a compile error):

```
public Lion(String[] eats) {
    this.eats = steak, celery; 
}
```

I have created these two food objects in a food class, each individual food item has a specified health value and waste value. Here is my food class:

```
public class Food {
    int healthGain;
    int wasteGain;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Food steak = new Food();
        steak.healthGain = +3;
        steak.wasteGain = 4;
        //same but for celery instead
    }
}
```

I am really confused as I am meant to have an array of strings for the foods each animal eats, but I have created food objects not strings(the spec does not ask me to do this I just couldnt see another way to do it). Is there a better way to do this? or can I alter my code to make it compile? Either way the food each animal eats must be an array of strings. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's with the Food class? What is the original question from your school?

Answer (score 1):

Your Lion should probably look like this:

```
class Lion extends Animal{

    public Lion() {
        super(new String[]{"steak", "celery"});
    }

    //...

}
```

Notice that we don't actually need any arguments in constructor since we already know what food Lion eats and it would be bad to ask user to provide this information each time we create Lion object.

---

BTW if you want to avoid repeating this `new String[]{...}` code try changing your `Animal` constructor to use [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html)

```
public Animal (String... eats) {
//                   ^^^
    this.eats = eats;
}
```

This will still allow you to see `eats` as array of Strings (`String[]`) so you can assign it to `this.eats` without any problem, but now Lion constructor can look like:

```
public Lion() {
    super("steak", "celery");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short sample on how to proceed:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    // Initialize this array with food types
    String[] foods = new String[] {"celery", "meat"}; 
    Lion lion = new Lion(foods); // Pass in the foods as an argument
}

public Lion(String[] eats) {
    super(eats); // Call the overloaded Animal constructor
}
```

Comment: Why bother passing the eats arg into the Lion constructor? Nothing is done with it

Comment: @robjwilkins he just wants to the code to compile; I posted the preferred alternative.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should do:

```
class Lion extends Animal
{
    public Lion(String[] eats) {
        super(eats); //invoke superclass constructor
    }
}
```

Since `eats` is not private, it will be inherited. Also remember to invoke superclass's constructor, else you will get a compilation error.

You don't hard code what Lion eats within Lion class. You do it in the main():

```
//In the main method
String[] eats = {"celery", "steak"};
new Lion(eats);
```